# Does iPhone 6 still report the same width in portrait and landscape?

Tags: ios, ios8, media-queries, screen-size, iphone-6

I can't seem to find an answer for this, and I don't have access to an iPhone 6 or 6 Plus.

All previous iOS devices would always report their width as the width of the device in portrait mode, even if they knew they were in landscape mode. I'm wondering if we need to create even more specialized media queries for the new devices with their new screen sizes, or if they're finally reporting the correct width in landscape mode.

Thanks!

- I should add, I'm asking mostly in terms of CSS Media Queries, when we're checking for `width` or `device-width`. For example, older iOS devices would report `device-width` as 768px in both portrait and landscape mode.

Comment: Have you tried using Chrome developer tools to simulate iPhone 6/6 Plus?

Comment: I'm not very trusting of their Device Mode right now (i have another post on here about a bug i ran into) but I'll give it a shot.

Comment: just to follow up, I do have a 3rd gen iPad and when I open up the screen size test at http://quirksmode.org/m/tests/widthtest.html I do get the same width of 980px being reported in both portrait and landscape. Emulating it in Device Mode and going to the same page, I get different values (which should be correct in a perfect world). But as I suspected, it's not fully emulating what I actually get on my device.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With regards to iOS specifically, the best practice for determining width of device viewport is to use CSS `orientation` media query. 768px is only for older iPads. Here's a list of queries you should use for each device instance:

---

**iPhone 6:**

```
@media only screen 
and (min-device-width : 375px) 
and (max-device-width : 667px) { /* STYLES GO HERE */}
```

**iPhone 6 Plus:**

```
@media only screen 
and (min-device-width : 540px) 
and (max-device-width : 960px) { /* STYLES GO HERE */}
```

If you want your CSS to be applied specific to the context of portrait or landscape, then you'd need to add an `orientation` query as well for that specific case.

Comment: Hi Xenyal, I have a script that first gets the orientation of any device viewing the page, and then runs through media queries based on `min-` and `max-width`. The problem is, iOS devices lie about their width (it's the same in portrait or landscape). My script is trying to load up the most appropriate background image for the device, so I do already have specialized queries for older iOS devices that are lying to us, but I'd like to know if iPhone 6 is continuing that tradition - reporting the same width in portrait and landscape mode - or if my generic, catch-all queries would work.

Comment: @LubosB Script as in Javascript? Regarding iPhone 6/6Plus, it is true that their width will not change based on their orientation. So the ideal solution would be to have queries that include `orientation`, as well as `width` for your case.

Comment: Thanks for confirming. Yes, JS, so maybe I will just write a function that does something like `if (orientation == landscape && width < height)` ... load up a landscape image (instead of having 4 different queries to cover all iOS devices).

Comment: It's generally considered better practice to address different CSS cases by illustrating all of them in your .css file. Keep Javascript limited to behavioral cases that lead to DOM element class changes. So you'd have a different `background-image` based on CSS media queries.